# Strange behaviour with Gaussian random distribution

Tags: python, random, gaussian

I'm running a bit of code whose purpose is to take a list/array of floats and an associated list/array of the same length acting as an "error" and shuffle the first list around according to a Gaussian distribution.

This is a `MWE` of the code:

```
import random
import numpy as np

def random_data(N, a, b):
    # Generate some random data.
    return np.random.uniform(a, b, N).tolist()

# Obtain values for x.
x = random_data(100, 0., 1.)
# Obtain error/sigma values for x.
x_sigma = random_data(100, 0., 0.2)

# Generate new x values shuffling each float around a
# Gaussian distribution with a given sigma.
x_gauss = random.gauss(np.array(x), np.array(x_sigma))

print x-x_gauss
```

What I find is that the result of doing `x-x_gauss` is a list of floats that is **always either positive or negative**. This means the `random.gauss` call is always assigning either a larger new value for each float in `x` or a smaller one *for all values in `x`*.

I would expect the `random.gauss` call to shuffle the floats in `x` around its values both to the right and to the left, since this is a random process.

Why is this not happening? Am I understanding something wrong about the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [definition of random.gauss](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/03fc7449f204/Lib/random.py#l541):

```
def gauss(self, mu, sigma):
    random = self.random
    z = self.gauss_next
    self.gauss_next = None
    if z is None:
        x2pi = random() * TWOPI
        g2rad = _sqrt(-2.0 * _log(1.0 - random()))
        z = _cos(x2pi) * g2rad
        self.gauss_next = _sin(x2pi) * g2rad

    return mu + z*sigma
```

Notice that is is generating *one* value for `z`, and returning `mu + z*sigma`.
Since `mu` and `sigma` are numpy arrays, this calculation is being done element-wise. Since `sigma` is positive, the shift `z*sigma` is either always positive or negative, depending on the sign of `z`

---

If you are using NumPy, unless there is a specific reason to do otherwise, I would use the `np.random` module to generate these values. It would be quicker than using a Python loop with calls to `random.gauss`:

```
import numpy as np

N = 100
x = np.random.uniform(0., 1., size=N)
x_sigma = np.random.uniform(0., 0.2, size=N)

z = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=N)
x_gauss = x + z*x_sigma

print x-x_gauss
```

Comment: Oh I see, so I should do this recursively in a `for` loop to get a different random shuffle for each float or is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Never mind, I'll just close this one make a new question regarding that to avoid mixing things up. Thank you @unutbu!

Comment: Well, no need to open that other question now that you wrote that great code to replace my faulty one. Thank you very much again!